# How do I use MapLibre-GL from TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, maplibre-gl

I am trying to show a MapLibre map in a simple web page using TypeScript.

The example on the MapLibre web site uses JavaScript, I want to do the same thing in TypeScript.

Here's my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@3.3.1/dist/maplibre-gl.css' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@3.3.1/dist/maplibre-gl.js'></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>var exports = {};</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my script.ts:

```js
import MapLibreGL from 'maplibre-gl';

const map = new MapLibreGL.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'https://demotiles.maplibre.org/style.json', // style URL
    center: [0, 0], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 1 // starting zoom
});
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I get the following error in the browser console window:

***'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at script.ts:1:1'***

I am using Visual Studio Pro 2022. I've also tried it in VSCode with similar results.

Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

Is there a sample on the web that shows how to do it? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: what typescript bundling are you using? I would recommend setting up an example project with [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) -- a TypeScript sample project that is (use the Vanilla configuration i.e. no framework) -- and then you will be able to `npm install maplibre-gl` and `import maplibregl from "maplibre-gl";` from typescript